# Set new Activity to be below current one

Tags: android, android-activity, z-order

I am creating a custom transition animation between two activities. By default, the new Activity is `above` the current one.

**Is it possible to make the new Activity to be `below` current Activity? And if it is possible, then How to implement this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best practice but try this:

In old activity:

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(newActivity);
```

Then in your new Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_activity);
    Intent oldActivity= new Intent(this, OldActivity.class);
    oldActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(oldActivity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible you can use Fragments to do so..
convert those Activities to Fragments and create a Activity and place those Fragments in Activity.

Ref :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html